# fetching address label from transaction info

Tags: blockchain, transactions, addresses, explorers, explorer-api

while fetching transaction JSON for the given address, I want to fetch the address label associated with the address, for example, here's an example of how Moralis streams provide it for EVM chains,

```
 {
  "hash": "0x1ed85b3757a6d31d01a4d6677fc52fd3911d649a0af21fe5ca3f886b153773ed",
  "nonce": "1848059",
  "transaction_index": "108",
  "from_address": "0x267be1c1d684f78cb4f6a176c4911b741e4ffdc0",
  "to_address": "0x003dde3494f30d861d063232c6a8c04394b686ff",

  "from_address_label": "Binance 1",
  "to_address_label": "Binance 2",

  "value": "115580000000000000",
  "gas": "30000",
  "gas_price": "52500000000",
  "input": "0x",
  "receipt_cumulative_gas_used": "4923073",
  "receipt_gas_used": "21000",
  "receipt_status": "1",
  "block_timestamp": "2021-05-07T11:08:35.000Z",
  "block_number": "12386788",
.......
  }
}
```

can anyone please guide me on how can i achieve the same for multiple chains, like for a BTC, BTC cash, Solana transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can anyone please guide me on how can i achieve the same for multiple chains, like for a BTC, BTC cash, Solana transaction.

It is not possible without buying the label data from somewhere, like Nansen or Arkham.